# How to display data in the dropdownlist for the Dev express mvc grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have a dev express grid with 3 columns in it and I want the 3rd column to be editable.

When a user clicks on edit then a drop down list should display for that row (only in the 3rd column), but each row should have a different drop down list as I want to pull data from different stored procedures based on the field name.

So, I am able to get a grid with 3 columns and first two columns are non-editable and also, I have a drop down for the 3rd column but I do not know h`o`w to display the data in the drop down for each row. That is where I am stuck.

This is what I have written so far :-

Partial View :-

```
settings.Columns.Add(col =>
    {
        col.FieldName = "DefaultValue";
        col.Caption = "Rule Type Value";
        col.Width = 300;
        col.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.DropDownEdit;
        col.SetEditItemTemplateContent(column =>
        {
            Html.DevExpress().DropDownEdit(c =>
            {
                c.Name = "ddlName";
                c.SetDropDownWindowTemplateContent("WHAT GOES HERE!?!?!");
            }).Render();
        });
    });
```

It would be great if anybody can help me on that.

If I have not given adequate information to explain this question then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For your dropdownedit you want to add items this way:

```
c.Properties.Items.Add("Item 1");
c.Properties.Items.Add("Item 2");
```